# Struggling to position element at centre of area below header

Tags: polymer

I have a single page app which I experimenting a bit with layout.  Whilst I try to understand it, I am trying to position a  element at the centre of the content area of a  element. I am using  as the header of all of this.

Here is the overall form of the body area of my index.html

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
 <template id="app" is="dom-bind">
  <paper-header-panel class="flex" mode="standard">
  <paper-toolbar> ... </paper-toolbar>
  <neon-animated-pages
    class="flex"
    selected="[[route]]"
    attr-for-selected="selector"
    entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
    exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <pas-menu path="/" selector="home" route="{{route}}" access=[[user.keys]]></pas-menu>
  .............. More elements
  </neon-animated-pages>
</paper-header-panel>
```

Looking at my  element

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../pas-route-behaviour/pas-route-behaviour.html">
 <template>
<style>
  paper-card: {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
  }
</style>
<div class="vertical layout center">
  <div class="horizontal layout">
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <paper-card heading="PAS MENU to go here"></paper-card>
    <div class="flex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'pas-menu',
  behaviors :[PAS.RouteBehaviour,Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior],
  properties: {
    access: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
    }
  }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

When I load all this up and look at the result with the chome dev tools I find that the  element has zero height and the only height I can seemingly introduce it the Text of the paper card and its padding.

The net result is the card sits in the top of the content area (centered), with the card size just that to surround the text.  Why have I lost the height of the full screen and what do I need to do to centre the card vertically.

Comment: Can you include your imports?

Comment: editited to include imports to pas-menu element

Answer (score 1):

The only mistake you are doing here is in your style section, the selector for the paper-card is

`paper-card`  and not `paper-card:` 
Also give a background-color or a shadow to your paper-card if you want to see it,
Both `<div class='flex'></div>` are not useful because the parent div is already centered. Finally your element shoud look like

```js
<dom-module id="pas-menu">
<template>
<style>
  :host
  {
    @apply(--layout-vertical);  // vertical layout for the host of pas-menu
    @apply(--layout-center-center); // make the host center its element
    // or if you want you to keep it simple
    // display:box 
    top: 350px; // margin-top for the element pas-menu
    
    }
  paper-card {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:gray // color to the paper-card or 
    @apply(--shadow-elevation-2dp);// use the predifined mixin for shadow elevation
  }
</style>
<div class="vertical layout center">
  <div class="horizontal layout">
   
    <paper-card heading="PAS MENU to go here"></paper-card>
  
  </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'pas-menu',
  behaviors :[PAS.RouteBehaviour,Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior],
  properties: {
    access: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
    }
  }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

:

Comment: It solves the problem of getting the width and height of the card correct, but it doesn't really solve the problem of the pas-menu element having 0 height after being styled by neon-animated-pages to be position:absolute, and top, bottom, left and right all being 0.  so the car stays at the top of the page.

Comment: For that I think, you should add some css style for positioning your element in his  host , I edited the answer above by adding a selector for host

Comment: Thanks, rather than muck about much more, I have actually started to configure this page how it is ultimately meant to be and I seem to be succeeding.  A lot of reading of reading of the flex box article on the Polymer Elements Catalog site means I seem to have got the content laid out how I wanted it.